# Checking for subset in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I'm trying to flag some price data as "stale" if the quoted price of the security hasn't changed over lets say 3 trading days. I'm currently trying it with:

```
firm["dev"] = np.std(firm["Price"],firm["Price"].shift(1),firm["Price"].shift(2))
firm["flag"] == np.where(firm["dev"] = 0, 1, 0)
```

But I'm getting nowhere with it. This is what my dataframe would look like.

| Index | Price | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 11 | 0 |
| 3 | 12 | 0 |
| 4 | 12 | 0 |
| 5 | 12 | 1 |
| 6 | 11 | 0 |
| 7 | 13 | 0 |

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay with other conditions, you can first check if `series.diff` equals 0 and take cumsum to check if you have a cumsum of 2 (n-1). Also check if the next row is equal to current, when both these conditions suffice, assign a flag of 1 else 0.

```
n=3
firm['Flag'] = (firm['Price'].diff().eq(0).cumsum().eq(n-1) & 
                firm['Price'].eq(firm['Price'].shift())).astype(int)
```

---

EDIT, to make it a generalized function with consecutive n, use this:

```
def fun(df,col,n):
    c = df[col].diff().eq(0)
    return (c|c.shift(-1)).cumsum().ge(n) & df[col].eq(df[col].shift())
```

---

```
firm['flag_2'] = fun(firm,'Price',2).astype(int)
firm['flag_3'] = fun(firm,'Price',3).astype(int)

print(firm)

       Price  Flag  flag_2  flag_3
Index                             
1         10     0       0       0
2         11     0       0       0
3         12     0       0       0
4         12     0       1       0
5         12     1       1       1
6         11     0       0       0
7         13     0       0       0
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what n does. when I set n=2, i would expect the flag to come up twice, as there are two sequences of repeating values. but instead I still only get one.

Comment: @germany `n` is the `no of days you want to check consecutive values for` ,so when you set n=1, it should return Flag as 1 on the second consecutive value of Price

Comment: I see, but if I add a couple of prices = 12, I'm still only seeing one flag in the Flag column. How would you apply your formula to flag each time a certain number of consecutive values is equal to each other?

Comment: @germany updated my solution a bit and added to columns with n=2 and n=3, please check if that (EDIT section) works.